# capture click event of submit button jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, overlay

I am trying to get the click event of a submit button on my form...

```
<input type="submit" value="Search By Demographics" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>
```

That is the button that I want to get the event from.

```
$('#submitDemo').click(
        alert("work darn it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        //$("#list").block({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' })
    );
```

This is what I want to do on button click.  I want to put a loading image around a div and then unblock later in a different function.  Currently the overlay pops up when the page loads instead of onClick.  What am I doing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
$('#submitDemo').live("click",function() {
  // your stuff
});
```

As  @px5x2 pointed that live is deprecate so instead of live use ON

```
$('#submitDemo').on("click",function() {
  // your stuff
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and removed by jquery version 1.9.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#submitDemo').click(function() {
  // do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to run your script when the DOM is ready, as well as providing a callback to the click method:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitDemo').click(function() {
        // do your stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Best answer. When I first read it I thought "Heck I'm already doing that" but then I looked...

Answer (score 3):

You have to encase your code in a function..

```
$('#submitDemo').click(function(){
    alert("work darn it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    //$("#list").block({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' })
});
```

But it is always a good practice to bind the event using on so that it attaches the event handler to the element when that is available.. So

```
$('#submitDemo').on('click',function(){
    alert("work darn it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    //$("#list").block({ message: '<img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />' })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For form you can also bind submit button click on form.

```
$("#form_selector").submit(function{
// Do your stuff
})
```

where 'form_selector' is id of the form of which submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You might haven't included the jquery library in your code!

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```