# jQuery not hiding divs (mvc 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 divs:

```
 <div class="lobsummary">
    <input type="submit" name ="sbmtbtn">
    <input type="submit" name ="sbmtbtn">
 </div>
 <div class="applicationsummary">
 </div>
```

I want to show `applicationsummary` when `sbmtbtn` is submitted so I used the below script:

```
  $('.lobsummary input:submit').submit(function (event) {
        $('.applicationsummary').show();
        $('.lobsummary').hide();
    });
```

But its not working.

EDIT: The divs are enclosed in `<% Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"); %>` which I am using to pass values to my controller from the view.

Comment: Don't use 2 submit button inside a form. It is my suggestion, You can resolve this problem but may be you face big problem in future.

Comment: You cannot invoke .submit() over a submit button. jsfiddle.net/cWeSJ

Comment: User onclick event handler for button. See this [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356794/capture-click-event-of-submit-button-jquery)

Comment: @Amit.. I have a for loop for adding submit buttons.

Comment: @suninsky.. the onclick event does show the div but hides the div immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.preventDefault()` it stops the default action

```
$('.lobsummary input[type=submit]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         alert($(this).index() + 1);
        $('.applicationsummary').show();
        $('.lobsummary').hide();
    });
```

Comment: great.. we could have answered more perfectly if OP has displayed the html structure..

Comment: @sudharsan I want the index controller to be called since it fetches the results for applicationsummary.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy is right,use `submit()` over a form:

```
$("form").submit( function () {
  return false;
} );
```

HTML on the client side will be like:

```
<div class="lobsummary">
    <form action="/"method="post">
        <input type="submit" name ="sbmtbtn">
    </form>
    <form action="/"method="post">
        <input type="submit" name ="sbmtbtn">
    </form>
 </div>
 <div class="applicationsummary">
 </div>
```

Just use click() to test your jquery selection:

```
    $('.applicationsummary').hide();
$(".lobsummary form:eq(0)").click(function () {
    alert(1)
        $('.applicationsummary').show();
    });
$(".lobsummary form:eq(1)").click(function () {
    alert(2)
        $('.applicationsummary').hide();
    });
```

Then replace the     `click` to     `submit`.

Comment: I am using <% Html.BeginForm() %> for submitting values to controller instead of a form. How do I change this for <% Html.BeginForm() %>

Comment: The method       `Html.BeginForm（"ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.method）` which apply to     `<% using(Html.BeginForm("index","home",FormMethod.Post)) %>` will create a form in client html like     `<form action="/account/login"method="post"></form>`.So it's the same.I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the form was submitted, it reloaded the whole page and that's why it was not hiding because it was going back to its default view. So I used `if` statements in my view to hide the forms.